# When registering drag destinations for file types, what types are available?

Tags: xcode, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I'm setting up drag and drop code and I need to know how to make the destinations register only for a few types. Some just a few image types: PNG, JPG, GIF, etc: and others folders, images, and video formats.

I see these pasteboard types:

```
Types for Standard Data (Mac OS X 10.6 and later)
The NSPasteboard class uses the following constants to define UTIs for common
 pasteboard data types.

NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeString;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypePDF;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeTIFF;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypePNG;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeRTF;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeRTFD;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeHTML;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeTabularText;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeFont;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeRuler;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeColor;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeSound;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeMultipleTextSelection;
NSString *const NSPasteboardTypeFindPanelSearchOptions;
```

Why not others?  Or do they have nothing to do with it?  (generally confused noob)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've registered for NSFilenamesPboardType, in `draggingEntered:` or `draggingUpdated:` you can pull the filenames like so:

`NSArray *filenames = [[sender draggingPasteboard] propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType]`

Then check the path extension and return the appropriate drag operation.

Comment: Useful to know, but it seems I worded my question such that I asked the wrong one.  Revised.

Comment: Ah. If it's image data you'd have to grab the data and analyze it yourself.

Comment: So why are there pasteboard types only for TIFF and PNG?  I've seen code with others.

Comment: PDF, TIFF, and PNG above are for raw data put on the pasteboard by copying them. Your question is asking how to accept drags, which only come as filenames or a URL. When you drag and drop a file it doesn't put the data on the pasteboard, just the paths. So you either accept file drags or you don't.

Comment: That's what I thought but Apple's example confuses me because it registers its drag & drop views with `imagePasteboardTypes` which the documentation says consists of `NSPDFPboardType`, `NSPICTPboardType`, `NSPostScriptPboardType`, and `NSTIFFPboardType`.